# Debugging JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a .net mvc site. On one specific page, the form appears to be valid (no error messages are appearing) yet when I click submit nothing happens.

The page has a number of popups and hidden options, so I suspect that one of the unseen validators is giving me a problem.

I have added the following code to the form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#regForm').validate({
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            // 'this' refers to the form
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                $("div.error span").html(message);
                $("div.error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.error").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Yet when the form is submitted, the validate code and invalidateHandler are not being triggered, so I cannot figure out what is causing me the issue. Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong here, to help track down this issue? My only other option is to remove all my validation, then reinstate it a block at a time until it works.

Comment: Are you using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in conjunction with HtmlHelper methods to generate your form controls?

Comment: inspect the page and please include the generate html, don't forget to check the console for errors

Comment: if($('#regForm').valid()) { //valid form } else { //invalid form } try this

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes we are using unobtrusive js
MidTwo no errors in the console, and no errors in the html

I have found and fixed my real bug, so now this is more of an intellectual exercise to work out why it wouldn't work for next time

Comment: What was the _real bug_?

Comment: And as a side note, the code you have shown will not be fired because of the way `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script initialises the validator.

Comment: One of the hidden popups validators could never have been fulfilled for the specific scenario that was reported to me, so the issue was actually a code issue further back in the pipeline.